# difference between %fl and %lf in C

Tags: c, printf, double, mingw, codeblocks

I am currently learning about C language data type and I try to print a double variable the compiler suggested me to use fl after I type '%', and I got 1 number in the end of precision decimal line. Compare to %lf it will print six precision decimals in total

```
double num=12322;
printf("%lf",num);// result is 12322.000000
printf("%fl",num);// result is 12322.0000001
```

I've searched plenty of place but mostly the difference between %f and %lf is frequently asked. Is my situation could possiply the same?

Comment: Are you sure that the extra `1` at the end is indeed a `1`? Or could it be an `l`?

Comment: `%fl` is just `%f` followed by a literal l (lowercase L), so the output is `12322.000000l`, not `12322.0000001`

Comment: *the compiler suggested me to use fl* Are you sure?  That's a *very* strange-sounding suggesting, and I can't imagine why the compiler would have made it.

Comment: @SteveSummit it looks like this:  https://ibb.co/w6SytmG

Comment: Which IDE is this?

Comment: @SteveSummit i use codeblocks-20.03mingw

Comment: change to a better font that clearly differentiate between `1` and `l`

Answer (score 3):

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("%lf",num);// result is 12322.000000
```

the length modifier `l` in the conversion specifier `%lf` has no effect.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 7 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> l (ell) Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion
> specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int argument; that a
> following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a long int
> argument; that a following c conversion specifier applies to a wint_t
> argument; that a following s conversion specifier applies to a pointer
> to a wchar_t argument; **or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E,
> f, F, g, or G conversion specifier**.

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("%fl",num);// result is 12322.0000001
```

where in the comment there shall be written the letter `'l'` instead of the number `1` as you think

```
// result is 12322.000000l
                        ^^^
```

the format string `"%fl"` means that after outputting an object of the type double due to the conversion specification `%f` there will be outputted the letter `'l'`.

Pay attention to that with the conversion specifier `f` there can be used one more letter `'l'` that is the upper case letter `'L'`. In this case the conversion specification `%Lf` serves to output objects of the type `long double`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually have a typo in your output....

```
double num=12322;
printf("%lf",num);// result is 12322.000000
printf("%fl",num);// result is 12322.0000001
```

is actually

```
double num=12322;
printf("%lf",num);// result is 12322.000000
printf("%fl",num);// result is 12322.000000l
```

The C standard says that the `float` is converted to a `double` when passed to a variadic function, so `%lf` and `%f` are equivalent; `%fl` is the same a `%f`... with an `l` after it.

Comment: it isn't an integer... but looking up the spec anyway.

Comment: yes, i checked again and it is 'l' letter, but somehow the IDE recommended "fl" for me, so what is it excatly?

Comment: @nomeiker: Can you please quote the entire message that the IDE provided?

Comment: I do it again... First, I type "%lf" and it mismatched.Then when hover the mouse on it, that one "fl" shows up and along with some other thing https://ibb.co/w6SytmG

Comment: @nomeiker: That tooltip does not seem useful at all. I recommend that you simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two correct ways of printing a value of type `double`:

```
printf("%f", num);
```

or

```
printf("%lf", num);
```

These two have *exactly* the same effect.  In this case, the `"l"` modifier is effectively ignored.

The reason they have the same effect is that `printf` is special.  `printf` accepts a variable number of arguments, and for such functions, C always applies the *default argument promotions*.  This means that all integer types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`.  So if you write

```
float f = 1.5;
printf("%f\n", f);
```

then `f` is promoted to `double` before being passed.  So inside `printf`, it always gets a `double`.  So `%f` will never see a `float`, always a `double`.  So `%f` is written to expect a `double`, so it ends up working for both `float` *and* `double`.  So you don't need a `l` modifier to say which.  But that's kind of confusing, so the Standard says you can put the `l` there if you want to — but you don't have to, and it doesn't do anything.

(This is all very different, by the way, from `scanf`, where `%f` and `%lf` are totally different, and must be explicitly matched to arguments of type `float *` versus `double *`.)

I have no idea why your IDE complained about (put a red line under) `%lf`, and I have no idea what it meant by suggesting, as you said,

```
fl, lg, l, f,
elf, Alf, ls, sf,
if, la, lo, of
```

Some of those look they might be nonstandard, system-specific extensions, but some (especially `fl`) are nonsense.  So, bottom line, it sounds like your IDE's suggestion was confusing, unnecessary, and quite possibly wrong.